# How to configure Confluent Platform Kafka connect logs?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am using confluent kafka connect service but it is not writing logs in `/var/log/kafka` . How to configure it so that it writes the logs in `/var/log/kafka` ?

Currently /var/log/kafka only has following log files -

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 cp-kafka confluent     0 Sep 20 14:51 kafka-request.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 cp-kafka confluent     0 Sep 20 14:51 kafka-authorizer.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 cp-kafka confluent  1622 Nov 13 15:43 log-cleaner.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 cp-kafka confluent  7611 Nov 13 20:57 state-change.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 cp-kafka confluent  1227 Nov 14 11:13 server.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 cp-kafka confluent 16683 Nov 14 11:13 controller.log
```

When checked further , I found logs written to `/var/log/messages` (which I do not want) .
Have a look at below `connect-log4j.properties` :

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c:%L)%n
log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.reflections=ERROR
```

I am struggling to find these basic stuff in Confluent docs . Please help !

Comment: It's probably not in the Confluent docs because the log4j settings haven't changed from the base Kafka project

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently, all logging seems to be redirected to standard output. To redirect logs to a file you need to change the content of `/etc/kafka/connect-log4j.properties` to :

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/var/log/kafka/connect.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c:%L)%n
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.file.append=true
```

For more details regarding `log4j` you can refer to [this article](https://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/). Also, @Robin Moffatt has written a very nice [article](https://rmoff.net/2017/06/12/configuring-kafka-connect-to-log-rest-http-messages-to-a-separate-file/) for logging REST HTTP messages of Kafka Connect, to a separate file.

Comment: You can add `-daemon` to redirect them to a file